# run Cmake and make in parent directory

Tags: bash, shell, cmake, makefile

I have a project which is in parent directory a. The script runs the executables in 3 different subdirectories. Example below:

```
      A
    / | \
   B  C  D
```

Now, I would like to compile the cpp files in B, C, and D using a scrpit from A.

So far, in my script, I remove all the old CMakeCache.txt and Makefile files and the CMakeFiles directory to make sure there is no overlap.

THen I run `cmake B/` followed by `make -C B/`. I do this for each subdirectory. But I get an error saying `CMake Error: The source "/home/ybouvron/Documents/A/B/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/ybouvron/Documents/A/C/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.`

Why am I getting this and how to I fix it? Seems like it's trying to compile the two as the same project, but in each of the CMakeLists.txt files in the subdirectories, they have different project names and executable names.

Thanks in advance.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo Deleting old make files

rm B/CMakeCache.txt
rm -r B/CMakeFiles/
rm B/Makefile

rm C/CMakeCache.txt
rm -r C/CMakeFiles/
rm C/Makefile

rm D/CMakeCache.txt
rm -r D/CMakeFiles/
rm D/Makefile

set -e

echo Compiling subsystems...
cmake B
make -C B

cmake C/
make -C C/ 

cmake D/
make -C D/
```

Comment: `cmake B` configures project in subdirectory `B` into **current directory**. `make -C B` builds project, which should be configured into **subdirectory B**. For in-source build of the project B you need `cd B && cmake .`, so `make -C B` will then build that project.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`cmake B` configures project in subdirectory `B` into **current directory**. `make -C B` builds project, which should be configured into **subdirectory B**. For in-source build of the project B you need `cd B && cmake .`, so `make -C B` will then build that project.
                    – Tsyvarev